# Fire an event when user moves out of speciifc route in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using AngularJS 1.3. Assume I have created several routes in my application. But when user hits a specifc route/url & then tries to move to another route/url, I want to fire some event. I do not want to fire this event on every URL change.

So only when user comes out of this url `http://localhost:9000/data/55677c/edit`, I want to fire one function available in XYZ controller.

Here is my scenario:

I have a page which looks like this:

```
<div class="well">
    <button id='edit-btn' type="button" ng-click='saveContent()'>
            <div ng-include="'components/grid/comOne.html'"></div>
</div>
```

`components/grid/comOne.html` page contains one grid and it has its own controller which takes care of data management of the grid.

This grid is shown in two pages. One in editable mode and one is non-ediatble mode. While user is in editable mode and try to move out of the page without saving the info, I need to fire an event in order to discard ant changes user has made to the grid data.

Please suggest

Comment: what module are you using for route management ?

Comment: @sirrocco: I am using $stateProvider for managing routes !!!

Comment: How are you managing state? Do you have a service where you have the grid data and using that in both controllers ?

Comment: @sirrocco: so grid is placed in `gird.html` file which is having a controller by name `gridController` & all the code is placed under `gridController`. I am using ng-include to include `grid.html` in two pages (in one page grid remains readable & in other page its editable).

Answer (score 0):

If the listening controller is a parent controller you could $emit the event.

Or you could have a common service like this:

```
angular.module('x').factory('CommonLogic', function(){

   var pageChangeListeners = [];

   return {
      listenToPageChange: listenToPageChange
   };

   function listenToPageChange(callback){
      pageChangeListeners.push(callback);
   }

   function pageChanged(){
     for(var i = 0; i < pageChangeListeners.length; i++){
       pageChangeListeners[i]();
     }
   }

});
```

then when leaving that url (track that via $routeChangeStart) you can call: `commonLogic.pageChanged()`

In the controller where you want to take action just:

```
commonLogic.listenToPageChange(function(){..}).
```

Obviously this should be improved to avoid duplicate registration of the listener ... etc.

I hope I'm not overcomplicating this. Could you describe your use case in more detail ?

Comment: Updated the question which exact scenario!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `$routeChangeStart`:

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

});
```

---

You can put this in the scope of your current controller which might be **edit** as your url says.

---

From the docs:

> **$routeChangeStart**
>   Broadcasted before a route change. At this point the route services starts resolving all of the dependencies needed for the route change to occur. Typically this involves fetching the view template as well as any dependencies defined in resolve route property. Once all of the dependencies are resolved $routeChangeSuccess is fired.
>
> The route change (and the $location change that triggered it) can be prevented by calling preventDefault method of the event. See $rootScope.Scope for more details about event object.
>
> Type:broadcast
>
> Target:root scope

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this fuction is not getting called when I move between the routes & there is no error. I add rootScope to my controller and the I add code you suggested but even when the route changes, nothing happens !!